# SSL certificate installation problems

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ssl, redhat

I have been following a set of steps provided here [comodo](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/637/37/)

**Step 2** advises me to place my .crt and .bundle files inside directory *etc/ssl/*

In my server with FTP it shows I have a empty *etc/* directory, I do not have any *ssl/* subdir inside *etc/*

**Step 3** asks me to find my ssl .conf file which apparently exists as one of the following filenames.

```
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf 
/etc/apache2/apache2.conf 
httpd-ssl.conf
ssl.conf
```

Using FTP I cannot find any of these files.

My Specifics

```
Linux 2.6.18-308.11.1.el5 
Red Hat 4.1.2-52
Apache/2.2.22
Centos 5.6 64-bit
```

**UPDATE**

I have been advised on another forum to create a folder tree inside *etc/* which would look like *etc/ssl/ssl.crt/* and then place my **server.file, **server.bundle** and **server.crt** files inside *ssl.crt/* - I have done this with FTP.

However I am still stuck with **Step 3**

**UPDATE**

Running command with SSH

```
yum install mod_ssl openssl

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.i3d.net
 * extras: centos.mirror1.spango.com
 * updates: centos.mirror1.spango.com
Excluding Packages in global exclude list 
Finished
Setting up Install Process
No package mod_ssl available.
Package openssl-0.9.8e-27.el5_10.3.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package openssl-0.9.8e-27.el5_10.3.i686 already installed and latest version
```

Comment: Try running "updatedb;locate -i ssl.conf" - if you don't have one you probably need to "yum install mod_ssl" - for some reason it doesn't automatically come with apache on RHEL5. Doesn't really matter where the certificates are that much, as long as you get the path correct in the ssl virtualhost configuration. Usual spot is like /etc/pki/tls or something like that.

Comment: @SomeLinuxNerd Hmm, I have been using FTP, that command you want me to run, must be done via SSH?
Also I believe I have mod_ssl, However the etc/ folder does not show in SSH when I run ls command

Comment: @SomeLinuxNerd Looks Like I did not have mod_ssl, is this step necessary - as it appears installing it is returning "No Packacke mod_ssl available". I have updated my main post with the verbose parts.

Answer (score 1):

> In my server I have a empty etc/, I do not have any ssl/ subdir inside etc/ - Should I create one?

I hope your `/etc` isn't empty, that would be bad.  On EL, the normal location would be `/etc/pki/tls/certs` for public and `/etc/pki/tls/private` for private keys.

> Regarding the top 2 files, they re out of the question as the directories themselves don't even exist. As for the bottom two, none of these exist either.

Where's your config, then? You should know this, but, run `apachectl -S` to find out.

Comment: When I check through FTP it shows empty /etc/, however as I said  above I was advised to make the tree etc/ssl/ssl.crt/
I get the feeling I am not supposed to be using FTP?

Comment: @cecilli0n Correct, don't use FTP to try to create stuff within `/etc`, though it sounds like your FTP server is configured such that it won't let you anyway.  Upload the certificate to your home directory via FTP, then move it to the correct location on the command line.

Comment: My FTP is configured to let me create dirs inside /etc and move the certs there. However as for the ssl .conf files none seem to exist on my server. Are you able to advise anything? Also I cannot run the command "apachectl -S" in ssh, it returns "command not found".
Also within SSH there is no visable /etc directory when I run ls command, all the other common ones are visible such as public_html, /tmp etc

Comment: So it seems my /etc folder does exist, just it doesn't show up with the rest under the plain "ls" command, I have to manually type ls /etc to gain access. Hopefully now the rest is straightforward from here